# P5.js - load from and save to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops, p5.js

I'm attempted to load a file from JSON and display it on a page - I have no problem when I hard code the results, but it falls over if I attempt to use a loop.

```js
let aliens = 1; // for the logic in the draw loop
let score = 0; // initial score variable
let json = {} // JSON object

jason.firstName = 'New'
jason.lastName = 'User'
json.Score = score; // assign score variable to Score JSON

function preload() {
    scoreJSON = loadJSON('assets/scores.json'); // load external JSON file
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400)
}

function draw() {
    background(0)

    if (aliens == 0) {
        saveJSON(json, 'assets/scores.json'); //     
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < scoreJSON.scores; i++) {
        fill(255)
        textSize(24);
        text(scoreJSON.scores[i].firstName, 100, i * 50 + 100); // concatenate these three?
        text(scoreJSON.scores[i].lastName, 300, i * 50 + 100);
        text(scoreJSON.scores[i].Score, 600, i * 50 + 100);
    }    
}
```

This JSON file is sitting in an assets folder:

```js
{"scores":[
    { "firstName":"Jane", "lastName":"Doe", "Score":"1020"},
    { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "Score":"990"},
    { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "Score":"750"},
    { "firstName":"Andy", "lastName":"Climax", "Score":"700" },
    { "firstName":"Jodie", "lastName":"Farmer", "Score":"500"},
    { "firstName":"Kiana", "lastName":"Taylor", "Score":"420"}
  ]}
```

I'm also attempting to save the score back to the same file after a little bit of logic, with no apparent success.

Comment: `i < scoreJSON.scores` <= you need a `.length` on that array

Comment: Oops! That's a pretty basic error :(